# how to add namespace to route file using custom generators

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-generators

I am generating certains controllers using rails generators, it is working as expected.

However, how can i add namespace based routes in my route file

something like

```
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
     get resource_one, to: resource_one_index
     get resource_two, to: resource_two_index
    end
  end
```

I see the following in the documenation under the route section `route "resources :people"` but i am not sure how to add namespace routing.

Thanks.

Comment: `route "resources :people", namespace: 'api/v1'` maybe? I'm not sure the method can handle more then one level of block nesting though. https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Generators/Actions.html#method-i-route

Answer (score 0):

```
route "resources :people", namespace: ["api", "v1"]
```

from your generator leads to result:

```
route  namespace :api do
            namespace :v1 do
              resources :people
            end
          end
```

(at least for Rails 7)